# Angular 8 fails to read response from a request if there was a large blob in it

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx, flask

I'm developing an API that has an endpoint to update a table with a large blob (15MB or so), this api updates the table then responds with a JSON.

When this endpoint receives a small blob (a few bytes), angular can read the JSON and show the result to the user. If this endpoint receives a large blob, it seems the whole request fails, as firefox shows in the console:
[image]

I don't think it is a CORS problem because all other requests I make to this server are OK, even this request is OK if the blob is small enough.

I am usgin Angular 8, Python 3 (with Flask) and Mysql, but I don't think it is a problem with the database or server side configuration (for example max_allowed_packet or innodb_log_file_size for mysql and client_max_body_size for nginx) because the server receives those exact same files in the insert endpoint and everything is fine.
If I save a 15MB file it is successful, but if I try to update that file with another file with the exact same size, then the error appears.

Another thing that makes me believe the problem is not on the server side is that nginx access log shows only successful requests (all responded with code 200)

So I think the problem can only be Angular, but since it works if the blob is small, I have absolutely no idea where the problem could be.

Here is the service that makes the request: (insert works fine with all sizes of blobs, update only with small blobs)

```
export class documentService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

    insert(file:File, tags:Tag[], permitions:User[], extraFields:any, type:string){
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('tags', JSON.stringify(tags));
        formData.append('permitions', JSON.stringify(permitions));
        formData.append('binary_data', file);
        formData.append('extraFields', JSON.stringify(extraFields))

        return this.http.post<Resposta>(SERVER+"/document/"+type, formData, {"reportProgress": true})
    }

    update(file:File, tags:Tag[], permitions:Usuario[], docId, extraFields:any, type:string){
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('tags', JSON.stringify(tags));
        formData.append('permitions', JSON.stringify(permitions));
        formData.append('binary_data', file);
        formData.append('extraFields', JSON.stringify(extraFields))
        return this.http.put<Resposta>(SERVER+"/document/"+type+"/"+docId, formData, {"reportProgress": true})
    }
}
```

here is the part of the component that uses the above service:

```
this.docService.update(file, tags, permitions, this.doc.id,this.doc, TYPES.INTERNAL).subscribe( r => {
    if(!r.error){
        this.setEditMode(false)
        this.hide()
    }
})
```

And I also have an interceptor:

```
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private progress: ShowProgressService) {}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let newHeaders = { 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('jwt') || ""}
        const cloneReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: newHeaders
        });


        return next.handle(cloneReq).pipe(
            tap((event: any)=>{
                if(event.body && event.body.msg && event.body.error!=undefined){
                    if(event.body.error){
                        this.toastr.error(event.body.msg)
                    } else{
                        this.toastr.success(event.body.msg)
                    }
                }

                // shows upload progress
                if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
                    let percentDone = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
                    this.progress.showUpload(percentDone)

                }

                if(event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress){
                    let percentDone = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
                    this.progress.showDownload(percentDone)
                }

            })
        );
    }
}
```

Edit 1 - OPTIONS Request:

Request:

```
Host: url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Referer: http://url/dashboard
Origin: http://url
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3
Date: Thu, 13 Feb 2020 20:30:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Allow: GET, HEAD, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://url
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
```

Comment: I can see in your DocumentService you're `POST`ing and that works fine, but the `PUT` call is failing. What headers are listed in the CORS OPTIONS response? It's possible a combo of the PUT and the size are causing your request to be sent as an unsupported request type (Multi-part, binary, etc.), whereas smaller data is being sent as expected.

Comment: just edited the question with the OPTIONS request. If that is the case, NGINX would list an error in the server, or something different from 200 wouldn't it?

Comment: Looks like your Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn't returning a compatible origin string. I see the header says `http://url` which looks like a string interpolation mistake.

Comment: Some background, CORS is entirely browser enforced. The browser is the one who is blocking you from seeing into the response data and throws the error. NGINX won't respond with an error, and will likely still respond with the appropriate data, it will just be redacted by the browser if the Origin doesn't match the Access-Control-Allow-Origin origins.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your OPTIONS response added, it looks like you're not correctly setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the server's response to the CORS OPTIONS request.

Try setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in your server's response to see if CORS is the issue, then replace the `*` wildcard with the appropriate origin you'll be using to prevent potentially malicious cross origin requests